# Set BitmapAlphaMode of SoftwareBitmap to BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to set the BitmapAlphaMode to Premultiplied, but I have a error as following. I was searching for the answer, but I haven't got any solution.  Could someone please explain thanks.

> > $exception {System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.Invalid format or alpha    at
> >     Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap.Convert(SoftwareBitmap source,
> >     BitmapPixelFormat format, BitmapAlphaMode alpha)    at
> >     App2.MainPage.d__8.MoveNext()}    System.ArgumentException

```
SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, 
                           BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8,
                           BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
```

Comment: It is impossible to understand the problem in this way… is "softwareBitmap" a not-null object?    You need to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumles upon this post.
I had the same problem, what fixed it for me was:

`SoftwareBitmap formattedSoftwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8);`